# Must a spinner be displayed when downloading data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app at times downloads some data from my server. When this is happening I pop up some text on the screen saying 'Down loading data'. Usually only displays for .5 of a second since the amount of data is tiny.

Is this enough for apple or do I need to show some kind of spinner to avoid getting the app rejected. The app isnt blocked by this process, the user can still navigate to other screens in the app etc, so i guess its non-blocking, so I dnt want the spinner on the middle of the screen.

Many thanks for the advise.
-Code

Comment: The spinner is not for Apple. Its for the user to let them know something is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your text would block the app I don't think Apple would reject it, it's just a state which you define and the user has to wait. You are telling the user what the app is doing, which is fine.

If you have a high latency network connection, like gprs, the 0.5 seconds can increase to around 5 seconds easily, so take that into account.

If you want to improve the user experience add a progress bar or an activity indicator. Don't use alert views, they are nagging.

Answer (score 1):

You would be completely fine with your implementation described. What I usually do is turn on the network activity indicator when I have small downloading transactions.

Look at the `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` property of [`UIApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)